# Segment tree implementation in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, tree

I am trying to code new data structures I learn in Python, and the following function is part of segment tree.

```
def query(root,interval,xy=ref_ll([False,False])):
    print interval,root
    if root.interval == interval or point(root.interval):
        return root.quadrant.reflect(root.xy * xy) #Is always gonna be of the form [a,b,c,d]
    a = q_list([0,0,0,0])
    if interval[0] < root.r.interval[0]:
        a = query(root.l,[interval[0],min(interval[1],root.l.interval[1])],root.xy * xy)
    if interval[1] > root.l.interval[1]:
        a = query(root.r,[max(interval[0],root.r.interval[0]), interval[1]],root.xy * xy)
    return a
```

I am expecting this to run in O(h) time (h is the height of the tree), but it does not, can someone point out the mistake I did. Thanks.

EDIT For an idea of the segment tree, look at http://community.topcoder.com/i/education/lca/RMQ_004.gif

The function's termination condition is if the interval is form of (1,1), i.e. it is a point and not a range. All the functions are implemented.
Working Input:
http://pastebin.com/LuisyYCY

Here is the whole code. http://pastebin.com/6kgtVWAq

Comment: Creating a tree (nlogn) takes less than 2 sec. While querying n times (so nlogn) takes about 40+ sec

Comment: I tried running your pastebin code, and after figuring out it wanted input got an error message: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with 10` -- you should modify so it will run with the same data as your example tree.

Comment: Your code looks like it implements an interval tree rather than a segment tree, because your query is checking your tree against an interval rather than a point.

Comment: Also, your test case is a bit confusing.  I'm assuming that it's supposed to be the input read by your go() function through raw_input, but in that case I would expect it's first line to be a single number rather than a pair, and the 4th line (1 -1) doesn't make sense as an interval.  It would be easier to interpret if you gave your test case in the form of code rather than an input file.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you are [extending a list](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#list) for every level of the tree. The average time complexity of extending a list is O(k) where k is the size of the list on the right hand side. The size of the list on the right hand side is O(h) so the average overall time complexity is then O(h<sup>2</sup>).

Comment: Actually the + was overloaded, anyway I have made it clearer now.